# Cat infected tooth

Tags: cats, infections

A stray pregnant cat is visiting us for food, recently I noticed that when she wants to eat she hiss to the food and stop eating. at first I thought maybe she has some bone or something stock to her teeth (because it happened to my other cat once), so after examining her mouth with a lot of difficulties that was not the case. also her mouth stinks which obviously is a sign of infection.

It's so painful watching her eating something even though I chop or mix the food so it don't need chewing...

So here's the situation;

She's pregnant (I guess she has 1-2 weeks to give birth) and semi-wild with an infected tooth.

I'm living in Iran and vets here only do vaccination, they're no dentist. that aside Iran like any other country is in quarantine, only food and drug stores are open...

From my previous experience I know that for cat infections vets here prescribe si-fixim dry syrup 1 ml every 12 hours but since she's pregnant I'm not sure about giving her antibiotic. as long as she has that rotten tooth in her mouth it's going to get infected again too...

She's in pain and I'm desperate, what do I do?

Comment: do not underestimate the vets in your country,they can do a lot more than you think they might have little experience in small animals but a bad tooth is a bad tooth in every type of animal.

Comment: @trondhansen Vets are all closed because of covid-19 break out. should I start the antibiotic?

Comment: You cannot be sure it really is an infected tooth, you should take her to a vet or emergency clinic. Something will be open for emergencies.

Comment: @SerenaT No emergencies for animals/pets, they're all closed...

Comment: @ElectronSurf do not give antibiotics until a vet has examined the cat.what you can do is to start feeding the cat food for junior cats,this have a higher energy content,the mother cat will need all the energy possible to fight the infection and to feed her kittens.

Answer (score 3):

Unless a vet gives you a different advice, **I would not give a pregnant or nursing animal antibiotics**. Si-Fixim is a broad-spectrum antibiotic, which kills not only bad bacteria, but also the beneficial gut bacteria.

[Practo](https://www.practo.com/medicine-info/si-fixim-200-mg-tablet-dt-10246) writes:

> **Can this medicine be taken during pregnancy?**
>
> This medicine is not recommended for use in pregnant women unless necessary. All the risks and benefits should be discussed with the doctor before taking this medicine.
>
> **Can this medicine be taken while breast-feeding?**
>
> This medicine is not recommended for use in breastfeeding women unless necessary. All the risks and benefits should be discussed with the doctor before taking this medicine. If the medicine is used, close monitoring of the infant for any undesired side effects is necessary.

The immune system of the kittens will be kick-started by the mother's milk and their gut bacteria, which are also fed by the milk. If the milk contains antibiotics, the natural immune system will be damaged or destroyed, which can kill the kittens or cause them life long suffering.

Instead of giving medication, please try calling a vet or an animal welfare organization and describe the situation to them. Maybe they agree to pull the tooth despite the corona outbreak. Even if they won't treat the cat right now, they can at least give you better information.